# How to align an image next to a tab

Tags: html, css, image, styles, alignment

I have been following this [guide](http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/) to create a tab for every product page on my ecommerce site. I need help as to how to get this tab to appear next to the product image. Right now the tab is displayed under the image.

Image CSS:

```
.product_image {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

Tab CSS:

```
    .tabs {
      position: relative;   
      min-height: 200px;
      clear: both;
      margin: 25px 0;
    }
    .tab {
      float: left;
    }
    .tab label {
      background: #eee; 
      padding: 10px; 
      border: 1px solid #ccc; 
      margin-left: -1px; 
      position: relative;
      left: 1px; 
    }
    .tab [type=radio] {
      display: none;   
    }
    .content {
      position: absolute;
      top: 28px;
      left: 0;
      background: white;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    }
    [type=radio]:checked ~ label {
      background: white;
      border-bottom: 1px solid white;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

I'm using a theme called [Pronto](http://www.wpexplorer.com/pronto-wordpress-theme/)

Here's the page's width and other details in case it's needed for reference:

```
.container { margin: 0 auto; padding: 40px; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
.container-left { position: absolute; left: 40px; top: 40px; width: 200px; }
.container-right { padding-left: 240px; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
.single .container-right,
.page .container-right { max-width: 1120px; min-width: 500px; }
.boxed { background: #d9d9d9; padding: 30px; box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15); }
/* Body, Main & Commons
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Would be very useful if you set up a jsfiddle for the code... And also explained more about what you are trying to do. Moving the tabs next to the image doesn't really explain much. Can you post a screenshot of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @robooneus, here's a [screenshot](http://i1350.photobucket.com/albums/p769/Stonecold_Stone/screenshot2_zpsc7daee6e.png) of the current state. I want to move the tab up next to the image so that it won't look so empty. I'm setting up a jsfiddle. Can I post my product links here for better understanding?

Comment: Oh, you mean the entire enclosure, not the individual tabs? Would be great if you could just post a link to the page... looks like it should be simple, but unable to tell without seeing the HTML, too (preferably just seeing the whole page). Also, is this supposed to be responsive or not?

Comment: @robooneus Hi, yes, I mean the entire enclosure. Here's the [link](http://cheapgamessales.com/product/1001-MiniGolf-Challenge.html). I'd like to see the entire tabs up next to the game's image. The page isn't supposed to be responsive I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try addin `position:relative;`

```
.product_image {
  float: left;
  position:relative;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

See how that works out for ya

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added it to the css but unfortunately nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

To move the tabs enclosure on your site to be next to the image use this CSS for `.tabs`:

```
.tabs {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin: 25px 0;
    width: 560px;
}
```

Important here is adding `float:left;` and removing `clear:both;`. The rest you can play with to make it fit the best.

Comment: In future, make sure you post HTML code as well as CSS (a link to the site or a jsfiddle is always best). The CSS by itself doesn't mean too much without knowing the structure of the HTML.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I'll provide as much detail as possible in the future.

Comment: @user35295 Happy coding! And please accept the answer if it answered your question.